# IFNULL in Database: Query Builder Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I Have Database: Query Builder in laravel, i want to implement ifnull in Database: Query Builder.

```
$priceItem = DB::table('trx_sales_order')
             ->join('trx_delivery_order', 'trx_sales_order.id', '=', 'trx_delivery_order.sales_order_id')
             ->join('master_customer', 'master_customer.id', '=', 'trx_sales_order.customer_id')
             ->join('trx_delivery_order_detail', 'trx_delivery_order.id', '=', 'trx_delivery_order_detail.delivery_order_id')
             ->join('master_item', 'master_item.skuid', '=', 'trx_delivery_order_detail.skuid')
             ->join('master_uom', 'master_uom.id', '=', 'master_item.uom_id')
             ->where('trx_sales_order.created_at', 'like', $soD.'%')
             ->select(
                     'trx_sales_order.sales_order_no AS SONO',
                     'trx_sales_order.created_at AS SODate',
                     'trx_delivery_order.delivery_order_no AS DONO' ,
                     'trx_delivery_order.do_date AS DODate',
                     'master_customer.name AS CustName',
                     'master_customer.customer_code AS CUSTID',
                     'master_item.skuid AS SKUID',
                     'master_item.name_item AS ItemName',
                     'trx_delivery_order_detail.qty_do AS QTYDO',
                     'master_uom.name AS Unit' ,
                     'IFNULL(NULL, trx_sales_order.no_po) AS NOPO'
                     )->get();
```

but i got an error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IFNULL(NULL, trx_sales_order.no_po)' in 'field list'` ?

Comment: `IFNULL(NULL, trx_sales_order.no_po) AS NOPO` is `trx_sales_order.no_po AS NOPO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DB::raw()` to use the native DB functions, wrap it like this:

```
...
'master_uom.name AS Unit' ,
DB::raw('IFNULL(NULL, trx_sales_order.no_po) AS NOPO')
)->get();
```

There are several other `raw` functions the query builder provides, as well.

[Raw queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)